# grab filename that triggered batch script into variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have a specific file that I want to open with the batch I'm trying to create.

I'm trying to do the following:

1) Grab the name of the file with the extension that was clicked which triggered the batch file.
2) Put that name inside the batch file as a parameter.

This is what I have:

START "Test" "C:\Temp\Test.exe" param1 "filename"

So I'm thinking the best way to do this is to assign it a variable in the beginning, but not sure if that's even possible? If so, then I can just add that variable to param1.

Any feedback/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Right, clicking on the file name. So I have in a directory in windows explorer a bunch of files with a specific filename extension. I want all files that have that extension when clicked to perform the original post.

Comment: Sorry, not "right clicking" I had a comma after "right" to imply you were right that I wasn't clear in my initial post. I don't want to right click any file. Only double clicking the file to call the batch. Thanks

Comment: No, that part is done and you can associate it with a batch file. I'm talking about using the name of the file that was clicked as a variable in the batch file associated with it's extension.

Comment: My question really has to do with adding a variable, not with how to open a file with a specific program. I can't expect someone to answer my question if they can't figure out how to do that, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to open a file named Test with C:\Temp\Test.exe using param1 and filename
Do this:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Temp
Test param1 "filename"
```

Comment: Thanks Mihal, that is close to what I'm trying to do. Using your example I want to click on a file named Example.prop that will open on Test.exe (this part I already have) but then on param1 it adds Example.prop in there. So I need to find a way to put the filename as a variable inside the batch.

Comment: The `parm1` is `%1` and `parm2` is `%2` as a variable for batch!

Comment: Oh and parm1 is the file name when you drag and drop a file into the application. If you want to write it without "" do this: %~1

Comment: Hmm I tried those and it's not working, check my scenario: I'm clicking a file named example.properties which triggers example.bat which has inside it: START "Test" "C:\Temp\Test.exe" param1 "-M" param1 %~2 ||| and I need example.properties where %~2 is

Comment: See my example:  @echo off
title Simple parm1 and parm2
if "%1"=="" (
echo TYPE IT LIKE THIS: test TEST TEST2
goto end
)
if "%2"=="" (
echo TYPE IT LIKE THIS: test TEST TEST2
goto end
)
echo parm1 is %1
echo parm2 is %2
pause > nul

:end